# Excluding strings from Xcode project search

Tags: xcode

I have objects with similar names and when searching the project in xcode for e.g. currentTrack, objects with a name e.g. currentTrackList also appear in the search finder.

Is there a way to exclude strings or pick out e.g. only currentTrack and ignoring currentTrackList from search query?

I have heard about Code Pilot but never used it. Can code pilot do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the drop down in the search tab (next to the search icon there is a downwards arrow in the search field), there is an option called show find options, in that there is a section called Hits Must:

Change that to match search term

By default its on contain search term